# How to use chrome-aws-lambda on a AWS lambda function created with Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, puppeteer, chromium

I'm trying to create this lambda function in AWS using Amplify however when I try to launch the chromium the lambda function does not return any value and the function end up timing up:

`"errorMessage": "2020-12-09T02:56:56.210Z 57402f8e-9fb2-4341-837d-bdf2ee6e9262 Task timed out after 25.57 seconds"`
I add the Layer as suggested by @James Shapiro, now I'm getting a URL return for the chromium but it still not launching it:

This is my function:

```
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    const pageToScreenshot = "https://www.google.com"

    console.log('page:', pageToScreenshot);

    if (!pageToScreenshot) return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Page URL not defined' })
    }

    console.log('launch:');
    console.log('chromium.args:', chromium.args);
    console.log('chromium.defaultViewport:', chromium.defaultViewport);
    console.log('chromium.headless:', chromium.headless);

    const executablePath = await chromium.executablePath;

    const browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
        args: chromium.args,
        defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
        executablePath,
        headless: chromium.headless,
    });
    console.log('page:');

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log('goto:');

    await page.goto(pageToScreenshot, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    console.log('screenshot:');

    const screenshot = await page.screenshot({ encoding: 'binary' });
    console.log('close:');

    await browser.close();
    console.log('response:');

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: `Complete screenshot of ${pageToScreenshot}`,
            buffer: screenshot
        })
    }

}
```

This is the dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "snapshot31baa866",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Lambda function generated by Amplify",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "chrome-aws-lambda": "^5.5.0",
    "puppeteer-core": "^5.5.0"
  }
}
```

The logs:

> START RequestId: 6dc39c75-0577-492d-b305-6d5c95778eea Version: $LATEST
> 2020-12-09T04:56:34.141Z  6dc39c75-0577-492d-b305-6d5c95778eea    INFO    page:
> https://www.google.com
> 2020-12-09T04:56:34.141Z  6dc39c75-0577-492d-b305-6d5c95778eea    INFO    launch: 2020-12-09T04:56:34.143Z    6dc39c75-0577-492d-b305-6d5c95778eea    INFO    chromium.args:
> [   '--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required',
> '--disable-background-networking',
> '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
> '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',   '--disable-breakpad',
> '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection',
> '--disable-component-update',   '--disable-default-apps',
> '--disable-dev-shm-usage',   '--disable-domain-reliability',
> '--disable-extensions',
> '--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess',
> '--disable-hang-monitor',   '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection',
> '--disable-notifications',
> '--disable-offer-store-unmasked-wallet-cards',
> '--disable-popup-blocking',   '--disable-print-preview',
> '--disable-prompt-on-repost',   '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
> '--disable-setuid-sandbox',   '--disable-speech-api',
> '--disable-sync',   '--disk-cache-size=33554432',
> '--hide-scrollbars',   '--ignore-gpu-blacklist',
> '--metrics-recording-only',   '--mute-audio',
> '--no-default-browser-check',   '--no-first-run',   '--no-pings',
> '--no-sandbox',   '--no-zygote',   '--password-store=basic',
> '--use-gl=swiftshader',   '--use-mock-keychain',   '--single-process'
> ]
> 2020-12-09T04:56:34.168Z  6dc39c75-0577-492d-b305-6d5c95778eea    INFO    chromium.defaultViewport:
> {   deviceScaleFactor: 1,   hasTouch: false,   height: 1080,
> isLandscape: true,   isMobile: false,   width: 1920 }
> 2020-12-09T04:56:34.168Z  6dc39c75-0577-492d-b305-6d5c95778eea    INFO    chromium.headless:
> true
> 2020-12-09T04:56:57.868Z  6dc39c75-0577-492d-b305-6d5c95778eea    INFO    chromium.executablePath:
> /tmp/chromium END RequestId: 6dc39c75-0577-492d-b305-6d5c95778eea
> REPORT RequestId: 6dc39c75-0577-492d-b305-6d5c95778eea    Duration:
> 25009.76 ms   Billed Duration: 25000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB Init Duration: 168.98 ms     2020-12-09T04:56:59.150Z
> 6dc39c75-0577-492d-b305-6d5c95778eea Task timed out after 25.01
> seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried installing a `chrome-aws-lambda` layer and then adding it to your function? See the instructions [here](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda) in the "AWS Lambda Layer" section.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a little, the lambda still timing out, but now I can get the chromium.executablePath

Comment: Why not increase the timeout to, say, 5m and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I had to increase the memory and time out of the lambda function, however, I don't think it would work without James Shapiro's help, thanks.

[image]